# how to replace unwanted characters and digits from time column and combine with date column in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe df:

```
No. Code  Date      Time

0   801   01-JAN-11 08:30:00+05:30 

1   801   02-JAN-11 08:30:00+05:30

2   801   03-JAN-11 08:30:00+05:30

3   801   04-JAN-11 08:30:00+05:30 

4   801   05-JAN-11 08:30:00+05:30

5   801   06-JAN-11 08:30:00+05:30
```

I would like to remove '+5:30' from Time column and combine the date and Time column in a datetime format and have it as a new column. How can i possibly do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and selecting first value by `str[0]`:

```
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].str.split('+').str[0])
print (df)
   No.  Code       Date            Time                 new
0    0   801  01-JAN-11  08:30:00+05:30 2011-01-01 08:30:00
1    1   801  02-JAN-11  08:30:00+05:30 2011-01-02 08:30:00
2    2   801  03-JAN-11  08:30:00+05:30 2011-01-03 08:30:00
3    3   801  04-JAN-11  08:30:00+05:30 2011-01-04 08:30:00
4    4   801  05-JAN-11  08:30:00+05:30 2011-01-05 08:30:00
5    5   801  06-JAN-11  08:30:00+05:30 2011-01-06 08:30:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using python and pandas right? Would probably be useful to see your code but if you check out the link it might help. you can use something like `strftime` to format it how ever you want. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful.